# Can 12.74V (iso 12V) result in a PC not booting anymore?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

My desktop PC doesn't boot anymore (no leds, no fans, ...).
Last week, we could get it started by toggling the power switch a couple of times 
but this doesn't help anymore.

I tried

- replacing the 3V CMOS battery and resetting the CMOS
- visually inspecting the capacitors
- measured the voltages on the 24 pin ATX connector of the PSU

I measured 12.74V on the 12V pin which falls outside the 5% tolerance.
(all other pins measured well within the tolerated ranges).

Can this 12.74V be the root cause of the not-starting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *possible* that an excessively high voltage could have damaged your motherboard and prevented the processor from booting, but it seems unlikely that a voltage of 12.74V would cause any damage. I would suggest that you try measuring the voltages under load if you really want to see if the power supply is working properly.

Comment: How can I measure the voltages of the PSU under load? I just bought my first multi-meter (which is a good indication of my electrical knowledge :-) )

Comment: You need to be drawing current from the power supply to accurately measure the operating voltages. This is not an easy thing to do at low voltages and high currents. If your power supply has a 3.3V output at 10A you need a load resistor of 0.33 ohms that can handle 33W of power. If you don't have some knowledge of how to do that you should just try swapping power supplies with another computer.

Comment: I think I'm reaching the limits of my current capabilities :-)

Comment: You should also know that these power supplies usually _require_ a minimum load on one of the outputs before they will regulate properly. If there's no load on the 5V and/or 3.3V outputs I wouldn't expect the 12V output to be in spec.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any mechanism that prevents the system from starting when the voltages are out of the specified range. Unless the voltages are too low for the system to power up the system will boot.